# What is "a small goblin-imp"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, character-identification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “goblin-imp”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9766/what-is-a-goblin-imp)

Gollum used the One Ring to hunt and fish for food in and around his cave under the Misty Mountains and likely would have eaten Bilbo had he gotten the chance:

> > Only a few hours ago he had worn it, and caught a small goblin-imp. - *The Hobbit*

Watching the film version of Saruman create his orc army under Orthanc makes it appear goblins/orcs pop out of the ground as adults. I don't know if Tolkien came up with that idea, or if this is another case of movie magic created by Peter Jackson. What is a ***goblin-imp***?

Answer (score 2):

I always thought it was a young goblin.

The film shows the creation of Saruman's Uruk Hai from the earth, not orcs per se.